# iphone push notifications not going to all mobiles and feedback also not coming back in php

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification

I am sending push notification to iphone devices.
Nearly 2500 devices are stored in my database table. But in that only 270 devies getting notifications and some devices may be uninstalled my app. Some working devices are not getting notifications. Mainly latest devices not getting.
 I am not getting feedback also for deleting devices from my database who are not using my app.

Here is the code what i am using

```
function send_iphone_notification($message)
{

$sent=0;

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM App where Device_type='iOS' ") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($num_rows) 
{ 
    $passphrase = 'passphrase';
    $badge = 1;
    $ck=realpath("ck.pem");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///integrating the ck.pem file to APN's
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',$ck);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server


$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
{
    return "Failed to iOS connect: $err $errstr";
    //exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$sno=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $sno++;
    $deviceToken = $row['Device_token'];
    $deviceId=$row['Device_Id'];
    $message=$message;

    if($message)
    { 
    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,'sound' => 'default');

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    //$deviceToken = $row['Device_token']; ////iPod Device Token

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    }

    if(!$result) {
    $f+=1;
    }
    else
    {
    mysql_query("update App set sent_date=NOW() where Device_token='$deviceToken' and Device_Id='$deviceId' and Device_type='iOS' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $s+=1;
    }
    // Close the connection to the server
}
//running feedback service
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $ck);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if(!$apns) 
{
//echo "ERROR $errcode: $errstr\n";
return;
}
//else echo 'APNS FEEDBACK CONNECTION ESTABLISHED...<br/>';

$feedback_tokens = array();    
$count = 0;

$feedback_tokens = array();
//and read the data on the connection:
while(!feof($apns)) {
$data = fread($apns, 38);
if(strlen($data)) {
$feedback_tokens[] = unpack("N1timestamp/n1length/H*devtoken", $data);
}
}
fclose($apns);
foreach($feedback_tokens as $ft)
{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM App WHERE Device_token LIKE '".$ft['devtoken']."'");
}
//feedback service close
if($s>=1)
 return 'Notification sent successfully to '.$s.' iPhone Devices out of '.$num_rows;
else
 return 'Notification not sent to '.$f.' iPhone Devices out of '.$num_rows;
}
else
return 'No Iphone Devices found';
fclose($fp);
}

$message='200 jobs have been updated';
$send=send_iphone_notification($message);
```

This is my code.  I think there is no mistake. But why notifications not going to all iphone devices. Please help me. and also feedback also not coming if devices are not there.

Comment: Code seems fine, check with static Device Token ..

Comment: notifications are going to some devices

Answer (score 0):

Is also valid to considere this part of the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html):

Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.

If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered to the device when it becomes available.

Only one recent notification for a particular app is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications.

**If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that were being stored for it are discarded**.

Comment: give me suggestions for changes in code and getting feedback